# Something overrides Google Chrome Start Page

Tags: google-chrome, vlc-media-player

I have installed an update for VLC media player and now everytime I start google chrome it opens www.Startfenster.de. I cannot fix it within the google chrome settings:

[image]

Comment: You downloaded VLC from a non-official source, probably “vlc.de”. Did you try uninstalling “Startfenster” from “Programs and Features” yet? It’s the official way to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

startfenster.de is a German adware, so there is little advice online in English. I'm adapting from [this article (from chip.de magazine)](http://praxistipps.chip.de/startfenster-de-entfernen-so-gehts_51857):

1) as Daniel B noted, go to control panel -> software and uninstall "startfenster"

2) Download & run some adware cleaner of your choice, for example "Malwarebytes AdwCleaner" or similar (no advertisement intended, it's just the first that comes to my mind)

3) Most probably, the Adware changed the shortcuts to your browser(s), injecting the page "www.startfenster.de" into your shortcuts, so you'll have to do the following for any browser shortcut you have:

a) right-click on shortcut (right-click second time if the shortcut is in the taskbar) -> click on properties

b) make sure the "Target" tab ends with "chrome.exe" (see image:
[target has to end with chrome.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsAj2.jpg)) (or explorer.exe, or firefox.exe, depending on browser...)

4) Since most machines come with Explorer (AND Edge for win 10!) preinstalled, be sure to repeat step 3 for those browsers

5) Done!

6) If you find other issues (or just to be sure), use some malware scanner to be sure your machine is clean

Answer (score 0):

Settings => Show advanced settings => Restore settings to their original defaults.

Comment: This worked, however Daniel B's solution is simpler.